# FBXSDK, using Quaternions to set rotation keys?

Tags: c++, quaternions, autodesk, fbx

I am trying to write a file save application using the Autodesk FBXSDK. I have this working fine using Euler rotations, but I need to update it to use quaternions.

The relevant function is:

```
bool CreateScene(FbxScene* pScene, double lFocalLength, int startFrame)
{
    //Create Camera
    FbxNode* lMyCameraNode = FbxNode::Create(pScene, "p_camera");
    //connect camera node to root node
    FbxNode* lRootNode = pScene->GetRootNode();
    lRootNode->ConnectSrcObject(lMyCameraNode);
    FbxCamera* lMyCamera = FbxCamera::Create(pScene, "Root_camera");
    lMyCameraNode->SetNodeAttribute(lMyCamera);


    // Create an animation stack
    FbxAnimStack* myAnimStack = FbxAnimStack::Create(pScene, "My stack");

    // Create the base layer (this is mandatory)
    FbxAnimLayer* pAnimLayer = FbxAnimLayer::Create(pScene, "Layer0");

    myAnimStack->AddMember(pAnimLayer);

    // Get the camera’s curve node for local translation.

    FbxAnimCurveNode* myAnimCurveNodeRot = lMyCameraNode->LclRotation.GetCurveNode(pAnimLayer, true);

    //create curve nodes
    FbxAnimCurve* myRotXCurve = NULL;   
    FbxAnimCurve* myRotYCurve = NULL;
    FbxAnimCurve* myRotZCurve = NULL;

    FbxTime lTime;                         // For the start and stop keys.  int lKeyIndex = 0;                // Index for the keys that define the curve



    // Get the animation curve for local rotation of the camera.
    myRotXCurve = lMyCameraNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(pAnimLayer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_X, true);
    myRotYCurve = lMyCameraNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(pAnimLayer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Y, true);
    myRotZCurve = lMyCameraNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(pAnimLayer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Z, true);


    //This to add keys, per frame.  
    float frameNumber = startFrame;

    for (int i = 0; i < rec.size(); i++)
    {
        lTime.SetFrame(frameNumber);  //frame number

        //rx
        lKeyIndex = myRotXCurve->KeyAdd(lTime);
        myRotXCurve->KeySet(lKeyIndex, lTime, recRotX[i], FbxAnimCurveDef::eInterpolationLinear);

        //ry
        lKeyIndex = myRotYCurve->KeyAdd(lTime);
        myRotYCurve->KeySet(lKeyIndex, lTime, recRotY[i], FbxAnimCurveDef::eInterpolationLinear);

        //rz
        lKeyIndex = myRotZCurve->KeyAdd(lTime);
        myRotZCurve->KeySet(lKeyIndex, lTime, recRotZ[i], FbxAnimCurveDef::eInterpolationLinear);

        frameNumber += 1;

    }

    return true;
}
```

I would ideally like to pass in quaternion data here, instead of the euler x,y,z values. Is this possible with the fbxsdk? or do I need to convert my quaternion data first, and continue to pass in eulers?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to go back to Euler angles, as you can only get animation curves for the XYZ rotation. The only thing you have control over is the rotation order.

However, you can use FbxQuaternion for your calculations, then use .DecomposeSphericalXYZ() to get XYZ Euler angles.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using:

 `Eigen::Quaternionf q(rw, rx, ry, rz);
 
  auto euler = q.toRotationMatrix().eulerAngles(0, 1, 2); //roll, pitch, yaw` But will take a look at `.DecomposeSphericalXYZ() ` as well.

Comment: Hi again, Using Eigen was still giving me strange euler flips, so i am looking into your answer. `DecomposeSphericalXYZ` gives me other euler issues,  rotating on different axes than expected. I am using: `fbxsdk::FbxQuaternion fbxQuat(rx, ry, rz, rw);  
  fbxsdk::FbxVector4 fbxeuler = fbxQuat.DecomposeSphericalXYZ();` and then taking the first three values `fbxeuler []0 as X, fbxeuler [1] as Y, fbxeuler [2] as Z. Is this correct? Thanks again!

Comment: yes, that's how it should be. Can you post some code that shows how the rotation should be and how it comes out? There may be some difference in the order in which the angles are decomposed. Also, check that you are using the XYZ rotation order in the FBX

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not work. Although [the documentation](https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_fbx_quaternion_html) definitely implies it should,

> Create an Euler XYZ equivalent to the current quaternion.

An Autodesk employee [claims](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-forum/quaternion-to-euler-angles/m-p/4018458/highlight/true#M479) that it does not

> DecomposeSphericalXYZ does not convert to Euler angles

and this is borne out by my testing.  In the current FBX SDK, there are at least two relatively easy ways you can convert a quat to what they call an euler, or to something suitable for LclRotation.  First is via [FbxAMatrix](https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_fbx_a_matrix_html)

```
    FbxQuaternion fq = ...;
    FbxAMatrix fa;
    fa.SetQ(fq);
    FbxVector4 fe = fa.GetR();
```

Second is via [FbxVector::SetXYZ](https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_fbx_vector4_html)

```
    FbxVector4 fe2;
    fe2.SetXYZ(fq);
```

I've successfully gone from an XYZ rotation sequence → quaternion → euler from both methods, and retrieved the same rotation sequence.  When I use `DecomposeSphericalXYZ` I get a slightly different `FbxVector4`. I haven't tried to figure out what they mean by "euler in spherical coordinates".

Comment: I've been dealing with the same issue.  I don't know what `DecomposeSphericalXYZ()` is supposed to do, but it's definitely not Euler angles.  Here are a few test results: I've been constructing `FbxQuaternion` instances with axis/angle rotations, then comparing the results of `DecomposeSphericalXYZ()` vs. `FbxAMatrix::SetQ()` followed by `FbxAMatrix.GetR()`.  An input of `(0, 0, 1)` / `180°` yields `(180°, 0°, 0°)` and `(0°, 0°, 180°)` respectively; starting with `(0.56, 0.29, 0.77)` / `87.34°` yields `(56.90°, -8.85°, 60.64°)` and `(51.88°, -7.29°, 69.12°)` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Years later, I hit this issue again, and found a simple answer.

After you have set all the keys that you need, just use this filter:

```
FbxAnimCurveFilterUnroll filter;
filter.Apply(*myAnimCurveNodeRot);
```

This seems to function the same as the 'Euler Filter' in Maya, or the 'Gimbal Killer' filter in Motionbuilder.